# How to use a double forloop in Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax

I have a python program which expects 2 arguments.

I am reading them out of a csv file and need them to run concurrently.

I am not sure if it possible using bash but I was trying to create a bash loop like this:

```
 for i in $(csvtool col 1 new.csv);for r in $(csvtool col 4 new.csv); do ./script.py $i $r ;done
```

Is this possible and if not, what would the alternatives be?

Comment: I copy-pasted this into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and it says you're missing a `do` after the first for loop

Comment: ... and missing a `done`. See: `help for`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, thanks too https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy who pointed me towards shellcheck.

for i in $(csvtool col 1 new.csv); do  for r in $(csvtool col 4 new.csv);do ./script.py "$i" "$r" ;done ;done

Comment: I don't know how big your csv files are, but I hope that you are aware that you create a child process for each combination of `i` and `r`....

Answer (score 0):

Indenting can help with reading your code and for anyone else reading your code.

```
# First for loop
for (i in $(csvtool col 1 new.csv))      
do
# Second for loop
    for (r in $(csvtool col 4 new.csv)) 
    do
          ./script.py $i $r
    done
done
```